# No Logic in Trigger Mike Wheeler vs. Trailhead

Tags: apex, trigger, community, before-trigger, after-trigger

So I am using two resources for working with triggers. One is MWM Developer I videos and the other is Trailhead. I have noticed that in MWM they insist that all logic should be in a Trigger Handler Class and that logic just be called via a method in the Trigger. They say this is best practice and one should not write logic directly in the trigger. When I am looking at the Trailheads for Apex Triggers it seems that the logic is just being written directly inside of the triggers. Any seasoned devs out there want to shine some light on this?

Answer (score 2):

Trailhead is meant to be simple. A trigger framework would be an unnecessary burden when you're just trying to learn how triggers work. Almost all experienced developers use some kind of framework, either an Open Source version or a homebrew version (I've personally written a half dozen homebrew myself for various projects).

A framework allows you to skip triggers during test setup, use dependency injection, etc. It also allows you to test trigger logic one method at a time if you want, without using real DML calls.

Comment: By trigger framework do you mean writing Trigger Handler classes?

Comment: @ThomasMcferrin Trigger Handler classes (in some form) are a general trait of trigger frameworks. They're a part of a trigger framework, and a trigger framework can encompass more things (like abstracting trigger context variables, offering a way to control trigger recursion, aggregating records to be inserted/updated/deleted, programmatic bypassing of triggers, etc...). sfdcfox's main point stands though. Trailhead is generally about introducing concepts. Putting logic into a trigger is simple and thus good as an introduction (even though it's not best practice).